# Перевести программу с паскаля на Си++

Tags: pascal, матрицы, c++

Я написал программу на паскале, мне сказали ее перевести на Си ++ , но я этот язык знаю плохо. Сказала подумай как? Помогите, пожалуйста. Мне бы увидеть иллюстрацию и все!

```
Program matrice

var b:array[1..50,1..50] of real;
    i,j,n,m: integer;

begin
writeln('vvedite razmer massiva n % m:');
readln(n,m);
for i:=1 to n do
begin
for j:=1 to m do  
begin 
b[i,j]:=(i+sin(pi/j))/(i-cos((i+j)*pi)/(i+2)));
write(b[i,j]:10:5, ' ');  
end;
writeln;
end;
readln
end
```

В общем это программа вычисляет по формуле элементы матрицы

Comment: @parol, что совсем не знаете?

HelloWorld сами написать можете?  

Тогда все что Вам еще надо:

  для ввода используйте 


cin >> m >> n;

обратите внимание одним "оператором" можно вводить (а следовательно и выводить) несколько переменных.

Синтаксис цикла

    for (начало; проверка окончания; приращение) {
        тело цикла
    }

Тип переменной указывается перед ее объявлением

    int i, j, k; // целые 32-бит


Матрица 50 х 50 описывается так

    double a[50][50]; // действительные 64-бит

Индексы с нуля, т.е. i,j-ый элемент `a[i][j]`.

---

В общем начинайте, побольше тестовой печати.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это работа за автора.

Comment: @KromStern, зачем закрывать вопрос с правильным ответом? Голосую против закрытия.

Comment: @Visman, потому что он полезен только трём людям: задавшему вопрос и двум ответившим.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, он все равно тут будет висеть и мозолить глаза.

Comment: @Visman, вроде бы, минусование помогает в таких случаях.

Comment: Вопрос сам по себе совершенно бесполезен, в такой постановке, на него можно ответить только готовым кодом. Я процитирую @nofate "печально то, что отвечая на вопросы готовым кодом, мы не мотивируем автора разобраться в фундаментальных вещах, а только поднимаем его ожидание получить готовый код в следующий раз. При этом ТС не осознает более глубокую проблему внутри себя, а видит проблему только в злых людях, которые не хотят ему написать код по неведомой причине."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях пояснения строки ниже.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <cmath>  
#include <iomanip>

//var b:array[1..50,1..50] of real;  
double b[50][50];

int main()  
{  
    //writeln('vvedite razmer massiva n % m:');  
    std::cout << "vvedite razmer massiva n % m:" << std::endl;  
    int n,m;  
    //readln(n,m);  
    std::cin >> n >> m;  
    //for i:=1 to n do  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ )  
    {  
        for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)  
        {  
                //Наверняка есть косяк со скобками  
                b[i][j] = (i + sin(M_PI / j)) / (i-cos((i + j) * M_PI) / (i + 2));  
                //write(b[i,j]:10:5, ' ');  
                std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << b[i][j] << '\t';  
        }  
        //writeln;  
        std::cout << std::endl;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```